# DMCA (Digital Millennium Copyright Act)

Tags: java, plugin, licencias

Mi pregunta es:

- ¿como reclamar los derechos del autor en un plugin `java`?,

No tengo mucha experiencia con esto, pero un comprador filtró mi plugin en algunas páginas y supuestamente ahora tengo que reclamar por DMCA.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Segun la pagina de la [DMCA](https://www.dmca.com/FAQ/Report-copyright-infringement) deberías tener un certificado o insignia, aunque dependiendo del tipo de copyright que le hayas añadido a tu plugin supongo que siempre podrás hacer algo.

Allí te explica los pasos a seguir, *lo siento si la [traducción](https://www.dmca.com/FAQ/Report-copyright-infringement) no es del todo acertada*.

---

## Informes infracción de copyright

Por favor, siga estas instrucciones al informar de contenido robado:

1. Nombre del contenido
2. Si conoces al propietario, creador, editor o distribuidor del contenido.
3. Ubicación del contenido robado (*por favor incluya los enlaces infractores específicos, y no la url general*: `www.dmca.com` no es conveniente, es mejor ser específico en la URL, por ejemplo:

   ```
    www.theiveswebsite.com/stolen_content/stolen_title?chptr_12234.aspx
   ```
4. **Certificado de Protección DMCA enlace o insignia Protección DMCA.com** enlace que se encuentra en el sitio web los propietarios del sitio . Esto nos ayudará a identificar la cuenta del propietario del sitio .

---

## Links de utilidad (*en inglés*):

- [CONTACTO](http://www.dmca.com/questions.aspx?r=sol2db0)
- [FAQ](http://www.dmca.com/Solutions/default.aspx)

---

## Evitar que nos puedan piratear:

*Antes que nada, decir que soy partidario del Codigo Libre y Abierto, pero las licencias son imprescindibles, y no solo hablo de las licencias de pago, ya que de ésas no domino mucho, pero hagas lo que hagas (ponte...), en serio, ponle licencia. Ni que pongas una [`BeerWare`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beerware) o una `GNU GPL`...*

pero

## siempre ponle copyright/licencia a tu código

---

Con copyright / licencia tendrás tu código protegido en el caso que pase alguna cosa, ahora bien, mi recomendación, a parte de esto, es que le pongas una especie de `AUTH_KEY` a tu plugin, para evitar el pirateo.

Simplemente necesitas un servidor / webservice / microservice o algo que puedas poner online para realizar una autenticación parecida a la que realizan los desarroyadores de themes de wordpress o la API de google maps.

Cualquier página que utilice tu código debera hacer una pequeña petición a tu servidor para comprobar (como mínimo):

- dominio
- auth_key
- *(número licencias?)*

Esa petición vendrá del dominio donde está siendo usado tu plugin y será del estilo:

```
http://www.dominiocliente.com/nombrePluguin?auth=HXCADOUFUEHFDLAKJVCNBEBE
```

Si la licencia **existe**, **corresponde** y **está en vigor**, la petición devuelve un ok, (normalmente es una cookie para no hacer consultas a cada segundo, pero aunque sea un `OK` estará bien).

En caso contrario, se le deniega el acceso y con ello el funcionamiento del plugin.

Comment: Muchas, pero muchas gracias!; Esto me ayudo bastante, el comentario es muy informativo!, Acutalmente uso un sistema como el que dijiste pero este se conecta a un simple pastebin, en ese pastebin se encuentro los baneados (id) y tal, Este "ID" se genera sola al bajar el plugin, pero lo que pasa es que me robaron un plugin mas viejo, el cual no tenia esto, entonces no puedo activar nada del sistema  *Anti-pirateo*, por eso mi pregunta, de hecho, no se ni donde puedo sacar un copyright de mi plugin viejo, creo que es imposible, o no?. Gracias por tu comentario (repito).