# Licencias en android

Tags: android, licencias

Tengo una duda acerca del tema de licencias de software, acabo de terminar un programa para **Android** que me pidió una pequeña empresa, por lo que me encuentro en el punto de tener que distribuírselo, pero antes de nada me gustaría "añadirle" una licencia de uso, es decir, para que no puedan distribuirla a terceros, copiarla, etc.

He visto que Google ofrece la librería `LVL` para tal propósito, pero, dado que no quiero subir la app a Play Store (ya que quiero distribuirla de forma privada) no se si sería posible usar esa librería subiendo la app a Google Play Console sin publicarla.

En caso negativo, agradecería cualquier ayuda/guía/consejo acerca de cómo proceder para obtener o crear una licencia de uso.

Comment: a ver si te ayuda... http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/23550/dmca-digital-millennium-copyright-act/23591#23591

Comment: Justo tenía yo la misma pregunta en mente para publicarla uno de estos días. Muy buena pregunta y muy interesante.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si la aplicación se subiera a la Google Play Store la licencia para uso privado no aplicaría.

**[LVL](https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/adding-licensing.html)** es la librería para verificación, pero no aplicaría ya que tu aplicación sería de uso privado.

Si la aplicación se va a distribuir en privado puedes configurar desde la consola de desarrollo Google Play un **[canal de uso privado](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en)** que es similar a Alpha/Beta Testing, en donde se envian invitaciones a ciertos usuarios pero esto teniendo la aplicación publicada en producción.